# JavaScript - Math.max(undefined, 0) is returning NAN

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```js
const obj = {};
console.log( Math.max(obj.number, 0) );
```

and I need to avoid getting `NaN`. For this, I am doing:

```
console.log(Math.max(obj.number ?? 0, 0));
```

But I am not sure if this is the right way, as there might be special cases. Any suggestions?

Comment: How about converting it to number like `Math.max(parseInt(obj.number), 0)`

Comment: @IbrahimHammed That won't help. `parseInt(undefined)` is `NaN`

Comment: @IbrahimHammed parsing `undefined` will still return `NaN`.

Comment: @IbrahimHammed still, you'll get `NaN`. The OP's way is the *new* way of handling such cases, we used to write something like `obj.number || 0` using the `||` operator. In this case, `||` and `??` will have the same effect.

Comment: What other special cases do you need to handle? If you know that `a` will always be a number if it exists, your method is fine.

Comment: A special case may be `BigInt` which is theoretically a number, although not *typeof number*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> console.log(Math.max(obj.number ?? 0, 0));
> ```
>
> But I am not sure if this is the right way, as there might be special cases. Any suggestions?

Assuming `number` is either missing or a number (if present) then your current solution is probably one of the cleanest solutions.

---

As an alternative, you could make sure `obj.number` is always present by using a default or initial value when you create `obj`. This way `obj.number` will always be present, thus `Math.max(obj.number, 0)` will never return `NaN`.

Answer (score 1):

If `obj.number` was a function, you'd also get NaN. I think you'd be best off explicitly checking for the type:

```js
const obj = {
  a: 1,
  b: 1234567891011121314151617181920,
  c: true,
  d: function() {},
  e: undefined
};

console.log(Math.max(typeof obj.a === "number" && obj.a, 0));
console.log(Math.max(typeof obj.b === "number" && obj.b, 0));
console.log(Math.max(typeof obj.c === "number" && obj.c, 0));
console.log(Math.max(typeof obj.d === "number" && obj.d, 0));
console.log(Math.max(typeof obj.e === "number" && obj.e, 0));
```

If you're confused by the check: `Math.max` coerces your inputs to a number, so `undefined` would be `NaN`, but `false` would be 0. Therefore, if the condition (`typeof a === "number"`) fails, we'd get 0, so it'd be 0 anyways.

---

If for some reason you want to be able to work with values that *can* be coerced to numbers, you can do something like (where `n` is your number):

```js
Math.max(!isNaN(n) && n, 0)
```

Comment: Note that this won't work if `obj.a` is a numeric string, though `Math.max()` will convert it to a number.

Comment: @Barmar but in the real world of code-writing, would you _actually_ want to be comparing these numbers if the input was a string instead of a number?

Comment: It's not uncommon for numbers to be returned in string form from APIs. Some database APIs return everything as strings.

Comment: @Barmar if you really needed that, `Math.max(!isNaN(obj.a) && obj.a, 0)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `??` operand is the correct solution here if you are sure `n` is never be a string or any other type except `null`, `undefined` or `number`.
It uses the right value if the left one is `null` or `undefined`.

However, if you are not sure in that, then you should replace `??` with explicit number type check: `Math.max(typeof object.n === 'number' ? object.n : 0, 0)` - this way you handle any possible case, so you will never get a `NaN` in the result.

Comment: "If you were sure that `n` is never a string"... you mean never a non-coercible-to-number value, right? You won't get NaN for `"1234"`.

Comment: @code It depends, `'123,4'` looks like a number to me, but coerces to `NaN`.

Comment: @n-- what I mean is that _certain_ string values don't necessarily yield NaN, like `"1234"`.